# Setting/Getting Objects and values from Ionic Storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm doing a simple weather app project for college and I'm having a real headache using ionic storage to return values back that have been passed in to storage.
The application is fairly basic, GET lat/lon values from an API, save them in storage and then pass them to another API to GET more information and display it on a home page.

I can get the values from the API initially straightforward enough and I've pulled the relevant information I need from the API, stored them in an object, cityInfo, inside a provider (below, this may be horribly incorrect way to do it so all recommendations are welcome.

```
private cityInfo = {
    cca2: "",
    commonName: "",
    flag: "",
    lat:  0,
    lng: 0
  };
```

then I've set the value in storage as follows

```
packCityInfo(cityData: any): void {
    this.cityInfo.cca2 = (cityData[0].cca2);
    this.cityInfo.commonName = (cityData[0].name.common);
    this.cityInfo.flag = (cityData[0].flags.png);
    this.cityInfo.lat = (cityData[0].latlng[0]);
    this.cityInfo.lng = (cityData[0].latlng[1]);
this.storage.set('cityInfo', this.cityInfo);
```

If I console.log(cityInfo) it prints the different values for the different properties correctly i.e.

```
cca2: "GB"
commonName: "United Kingdom"
flag: "https://flagcdn.com/w320/gb.png"
lat: 54
lng: -2
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to then access these values out of storage. I think the issue I'm having is around synchronicity. I found that the first time I try to save my settings the request will fail and say that the ".lat is undefined" but the second time I save my settings the request will succeed and I'll get information from the API request from storage.

My saveSettings() function In my settings.ts page the following

```
this.storage.set('city', this.cityName);
    this.storage.set('units', this.units);

    this.cityDataService.getCityDataFromAPI(this.cityName);

    this.storage.get("cityInfo").then((val) => {
      let cityInfo = val;
      // return val;
      this.weatherService.getWeatherFromApiCoordinates(cityInfo.lat, cityInfo.lng, this.units);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Returns
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')
at settings.ts:48"

The Services are pretty standard and just handle the http get requests so I don't think the issue is with them? (Could be wrong ofc)

```
getWeatherFromApiCoordinates(lat: number, lon: number, units: string) : void  {
    let weatherData = this.http.get('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + "&key=" + this.apiKey + '&units=' + units);
    weatherData.subscribe(data => {
      let currentWeather = data;

      this.packWeatherData(currentWeather);
    });
  }
```

The second time the saveSettings() function is run it will correctly display values but its pulling from the previously set values.
So for example I run

1. Dublin,
2. Dublin,
3. France.
   It will return 1.Err, 2.Dublin, 3.Dublin.

Each time storage is cleared it will run Error initially obv

I'm a little green around the concepts of promises and synchronicity so any help will be massively appreciated. (I understand the concepts by and large but not so much practically)

Comment: *I found that the first time I try to save my settings the request will fail and say that the ".lat is undefined"* where and when is that? Please provide a [mcve], thanks! :)

Comment: Hey sorry I added a little additional context will try get a fully stripped out example when I'm back at computer later thanks for advice - x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a race condition going on, http-request is still performing and storage value is not set storage when you are calling `get` on it. Setting data into ionic storage is asynchronous. If you need to wait for something to happen, you can always call `async ... await` on storage:

```
async doSomething() {
 await this.storage.set(...)
 await this.storage.get(...) // here is available!
}
```

Though you also have http-requests using observables. You can of course turn them into promises as well, or otherwise chain them so that you correctly have all data when needed.

I don't actually even see that you would need to wait for the storage here, why don't use **[`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap)** to perform the second request as you need the response from the previous to perform the next one. That is what I would do, so just a suggestion...

Service:

```
getCityDataFromAPI() {
  return this.http.get(....)
}

getWeatherFromApiCoordinates(...)  {
  return this.http.get(...);
}
```

Then the component would do:

```
this.weatherService.getCityDataFromAPI().pipe(
  switchMap(cityData => {
    return this.weatherService.getWeatherFromApiCoordinates(cityData[0].latlng[0], cityData[0].latlng[1], this.units)
  })
).subscribe(console.log)
```

If you need to save in storage for future purposes, you can always handle side-effects with **[`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap)**.

Comment: Excellent I'll have a look into switch map now that looks like it could solve a lot of these headaches!

Comment: Managed to solve my particular issue by converting the observable to a Promise. Thanks for the suggestion!